# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre estas dos formas en Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Cuál es la diferencia entre:

```
function sumar() {
    var suma = 0;
    var f = 0;
    for ( f; f < arguments.length; f++) {

        suma = suma + arguments[f]; 

    }
    document.write(suma);
}
sumar(2,3,4);
```

con esto:

```
function sumar() {
    var suma = 0;
    var f = 0;
    for ( f; f < arguments.length; f++) {

        suma = suma + arguments[f];

    }
    return suma;
}
document.write(sumar(2,3,4));
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

En la primera función:

- Siempre escribe el resultado.
- Nunca devuelve el resultado.

La segunda:

- Siempre devuelve el resultado con lo cual:

  - Puedes elegir si escribir el resultado con `document.write(sumar(2,3,4));`
  - Puedes guardar el resultado en una variable `var resultado = sumar(1,2,3) //resultado=6`

Si tienes que elegir una, yo elegiría la segunda que te da más juego. **Pero** todo depende de lo que busques con ella.